# Wordpress permalinks that include name and ID, but considers only ID

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs, permalinks

I have a WordPress site and I would like to mimic the way certain news outlets and portals generate their URLs.

For example, you have an article called "Man Loves Woman", and the CMS software will create an url like this:

```
https://example.com/man-loves-woman/55123
```

Where the `55123` is the real ID of the article, so

```
https://example.com/man-does-not-love-woman/55123
```

will return the same article as long as the real id, `55123`, isn't altered. Doesn't matter what sequence is possible, is it `%postname%/%id%` or `%id%/%postname%`

Right now I have a custom permalink setting:

```
/%postname%/%year%%monthnum%%day%
```

I'm not particularly happy about this, I'd like to have it `/%postname%/%unique_id%` where `%postname%` is generated like that by default, but it doesn't really matter what its value is, as the `%unique_id%` is immutable.

I'm looking over at `wp-includes/link-template.php` and `rewrite.php`, but I'm not very versed in PHP, but if someone can point me in the right direction, I would be grateful, I have some basic understanding how it all works, with a right nudge I could follow up and figure it out on my own.

Perhaps I'm looking at it all wrong and should concentrate on Nginx behind it and setup a rewrite rule that insert the `%postname%` which can be anything and simply use the Default in the WordPress permalinks settings which produces:

```
https://example.com/?p=123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display the unique id of the post after it's name, you can do that from `Custom Structure` inside WordPress Permalink Settings by adding this structure.

```
/%postname%/%post_id%
```

It is not working on localhost, but it is working on online website.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm using the custom structure already, but I want to make it that '%postname%' is generated properly, but can be anything, and that the engine uses '%post_id%' as the real way to fetch the article in question.

Comment: Your answer was the correct one. The solution Anand provided was not working. It's kinda strange actually, it was throwing an `undefined function` error in the logs for the add_action function. I should have mentioned I'm using WP 4.0, perhaps they shuffled some things around. Anyway, thanks, the solution was painfully simple. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into [add_rewrite_rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). Add the following code functions.php

```
add_action( "init", "so_27051693_permalink" );
function so_27051693_permalink() {

    //This rule will match : man-loves-woman/55123
    add_rewrite_rule(        
        '^([^/]*)/([0-9]+)/?',        
        'index.php?p=$matches[2]',        
        'top' );

   //This rule will match : 55123/man-loves-woman
    add_rewrite_rule(        
        '^([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?',        
        'index.php?p=$matches[1]',        
        'top' );

}
```

In both the cases, the post will be fetched using post_id . Ensure to flush the rewrite rules by re-saving your permalinks.

Comment: Anand, thanks for the help, I replied and accepted Hujjat below. This was maybe necessary for older versions of WP, but seems that with the %post_id% I get exactly what I want. Thanks anyway!